# How historically accurate is the TV series Spartacus?

Tags: historical-accuracy, spartacus-tv

I've recently started watching the Spartacus (just finished Blood and Sand and Gods of the Arena, currently watching Vengeance) and the events described seemed rather exaggerated.

While it doesn't bother me one bit and I enjoy the series because it is what it is, it conflicts a little with what I had already known about the romans.

For starters, even if the gladiators were slaved, I lived under the impression that the most famous ones, the champions, were treated much better, something that doesn't seem to be the case with Spartacus and Crixus.

The amount of sex seems also too much. The roman orgies are very famous, but the characters in the series have no shame towards the slaves and indulge themselves in all sort of strange practices.

And last but not least, it seemed fairly easy to kill someone and get away with it back then, as Batiatus demonstrated not just once.

Of course, considering the nature of the show, things are bound to be inflated, to make the series more entertaining and it's definitely working but still... just how much of the show is true and how much is fiction? I would to point out that my question it's not about the historical figure Spartacus and his story, but the roman society and his habits as it was presented in the show.

Comment: Don’t forget that it airs on the cable network STARZ, so it is allowed to have nudity, swearing, violence, drugs, etc. Like most shows on STARZ (and HBO and Showtime), because it is *allowed* to have them, it goes overboard and packs them in to the point of totally overshadowing the actual story and/or being unrealistic. (*Boardwalk Empire* was surprisingly decent, and I like *Game of Thrones* and *Dexter* because they have characters and stories that are good and keep the DLSV gimmicks to minimum-*The Ricky Gervaise Show* is great, but doesn’t count here.)

Comment: the common language was latin, which most people learned much like modern english.

Comment: couple misconceptions- in the show people watching matches give a thumbs down when they want the loser to die- in real Rome they would've given a thumbs up. Also acquiring and training gladiators was fairly expensive, so actual fights to the death were a lot less common than the show depicted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the Spartans were way more brutal than it was depicted in the show. Because, **the  majority of the things depicted are true**  - the characters **personalities** and all of the **battles** and stuff, as I can believe, but it's **not historically accurate** as far as i know.

Because it is focused on the lives of merchants and slaves, and low level magistrates and praetors in a gladiator school in Capua, rather than the lives of consuls as you get with most **depictions of Roman life**.

- The **arena combat is highly unrealistic** and stylized for the sake of
  entertainment rather than as an accurate depiction of the way
  gladiators truly fought.
- The most historically inaccurate area is probably the language and
  dialogue. The slaves were taken from all over the Roman empire and
  would have had little to no education in most cases. **They would
  have no common language** and what little communication they were
  capable of wouldn't have contained the verbose level of word usage
  the show is so fond of.

In other words the show clearly tries to maintain a level of historical accuracy while not losing sight of the fact that **it's entertainment and not a documentary**.

Comment: You guys do realize that the first article (from something awful.com) is comedic in nature and makes fun of the historical inaccuracies of the show, right?

Comment: yes, but that is useful. By making fun of the historical inaccuracies it actually reveals more about the accuracy per total

Comment: Minor nit: Spartans have nothing to do with Spartacus. Spartans were Greeks; Spartacus was an Illyrian  (I believe) who ticked off the Romans enough to be sentenced to enslavement and eventual death in the arena. "Spartacus" -- from what I've read -- is roughly translated as "spear user", and may have been his arena fighting style (or role) rather than his actual name.